# Fishpig Wordpress Magento Posts not showing

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

My site is: www.bambinies.co.uk

I installed and uploaded wordpress in a folder called 'news'.

My blog home is www.bambinies.co.uk/nappy-blog/

The archive can be found at: http://www.bambinies.co.uk/nappy-blog/2013/11/

This all works fine, except for posts. A 404 page appears.

I have flushed the cache in magento, and there are no errors on the wordpress setup within magento.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and that you have added the necessary updated to your wordpress folder's .htaccess file.  Go to your Wordpress admin, click Settings, them Permalinks.  It will give you the required .htaccess information there for your configuration.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I have tried this but I still get the same 404 for posts pages.

Comment: I added what you suggested to the .htaccess in both the theme folder and the wordpress root folder.

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled with your host

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed. An update was available on the Fishpig Wordpress plugin, once this was done the posts pages loaded.

Comment: Just want to mention that this problem was happening on a client site of mine as well. Past posts would load, but a newly added post would just 404. After upgrading the Fishpig plugin to the latest version the issue was resolved.